# Calculate the density from the accumulated curve

Tags: r

I calculated the cumulative probability (in English, cdf) of my data, based on the probability of exceedance (edf). No problem at all.

However, does anyone know if there is any command to transform this data into probability density (pdf)?

I have already tested using the histogram function, but it does not work correctly.

```
x <- c (0.00000000, 0.03505324, 0.07005407, 0.10512053, 0.14021308,
0.17533767, 0.21051443, 0.24570116, 0.28090087, 0.31592221,
0.35092739, 0.38591441,0.42085712, 0.45599341, 0.49119521, 0.52646341,
0.56159558, 0.59673546, 0.63172464, 0.66674853, 0.70177413, 0.73712542,
0.77225123, 0.80750715, 0.84250460, 0.87720473, 0.91172191, 0.94588810,
0.98056348)
```

Comment: The functions you want are of the form 'p'<distribution name>. IE if your data are from a normal distribution, then you want pnorm(x, mean, sd) - or pgamma, punif, etc.

Comment: Thank @OlliePerkins!!
Yes, I used this for other data. But specifically this data, I do not want induce the distribution (like your example, normal or gamma). I want the data to show me, what is the distribution the better matches the data.

Comment: Okay. The packages you want to check out are fitdistr and fitdistrplus. Beyond, that, the craft & process of fitting a model to your data is something books get written about, and is hardly going to be solved in one stack post.

Comment: If your data is discrete, `diff(x)` is exactly what you want. If it's continuous, I still have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Is the function you are looking for density() ?

You can plot with

```
plot(density(x))
```

You can see x and y values with:

```
density(x)$x
density(x)$y
```

Comment: I think `density()` is used to estimate kernel density of random samples or a set of data. It has nothing to do with the cumulative density.

Comment: Thank you @OlliePerkins! I don't have permission to install packages here.

Comment: Thank you @AdamWaring, unfortunately my way is not easy. I need to investigate a pdf using derivate, in this case, if there is no any function more directly (cdf -> pdf).